# Двоеточие или запятая

Tags: запятые, двоеточие

Скажите(?) вашей вере усиление не нужно?

Какой знак тут правильней поставить?

Answer (score 2):

Думаю, что:

- во-первых, выбор знака действительно может быть сделан на усмотрение автора,
- и, во-вторых, с двоеточием получается более акцентированная интонационная пауза (ну или назовите это логическим ударением, не знаю) после слова «*скажите*».

То есть «правильность» определяется контекстом, замыслом автора и т. п.

**P.S.** *Если же грамматически тут выбор знака однозначен, то прошу здешних завсегдатаев меня поправить*.

Answer (score 1):

Данное предложение можно охарактеризовать как  БСП с  изъяснительными отношениями между частями и поставить двоеточие, или СПП с пропуском  союза-частицы "ли" ( в разговорном стиле речи) и поставить запятую. Поскольку данное предложение носит разговорный характер, предпочтительно поставить запятую. Двоеточие более книжный знак.

Answer (score 0):

Вариант 1. **Скажите, вашей вере усиление не нужно?**

Это вариант, который обычно используется. ***Скажите*** — **вводное предложение**, логическим центром высказывания является вторая часть.

Вряд ли это СПП (союз ЛИ пропущен, вопросительный знак стоит в конце предложения, а он по правилам ставится в особом случае).

Вариант 2. **Скажите: вашей вере усиление не нужно?**

Это БСП с придаточным изъяснительным. Да, **логическое  ударение (тоническое и силовое) делается на первом слове,** так как далее следует увеличенная предупредительная пауза, обозначенная двоеточием.

Это более редкий вариант, так как фраза воспринимается как **усиленное давление на собеседника.**

Comment: @ Jasmin",скажите" -  это вводное предложение?

Comment: Если перестроить предложение "Скажите(?) вашей вере усиление не нужно (***ли*** ) усиление?", сомнений ведь не вызывает, что СПП?

Comment: Почитаем Розенталя.  Если придаточная часть СПП содержит косвенный вопрос, то в конце предложения вопросительный знак обычно не ставится: Однако, если косвенный вопрос содержит сильно выраженную вопросительную интонацию, в конце СПП ставится вопросительный знак: Скажите, пожалуйста, что это за огни? (Л. Т.); Я спросил, как же он стал отшельником? (М. Г.) Мне кажется, что в этом случае ударение падает на вопросительное слово, а на частицу ЛИ ударение падать не может. Да и предложение с частицей ЛИ звучит неестественно. По структуре это явное БСП, просто вместо двоеточия стоит запятая.

Comment: Нет, вы не поняли: я спросил другое. Скажите - это вводное слово/предлржение?

Comment: Да и потом, в БСП с изъяснительными отношениями запятая ставится?

Comment: Если фраза не носила бы ярко выраженный разговорный характер, спор о постановки знака препинания не возник бы. Здесь однозначно было бы двоеточие.

Comment: Ответы на вопросы. (1) Скажите - вводное предложение, так как к тематике вводных слов оно не относится (привлечение собеседника: поймите, поверьте и т.д.). (2) В БСП с изъяснительными отношениями запятая не ставится. (3) Разговорный стиль - особый функциональный стиль. У меня нет информации  о нем, взятой из общих Правил (в частности, разрешает ли Розенталь пропускать частицу ЛИ в разговорном стиле).

Comment: Вы пишете: "... так по тематике вводных слов оно не отноотся"

Comment: Вы пишете: "... так по тематике вводных слов оно не относится". Должен сказать, что вводные предложения имеют те же значения и те же функции , что и вводные слова. 
.

Comment: Я не вижу у слова "скажите" никакого значения вводных предложений. К тому же по структуре не подходит.